# Is there a word/phrase to describe fiction where the events, behaviours and the worldbuilding "make sense"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Please forgive the awkwardly phrased question - it's quite difficult to explain what I mean in a concise fashion.

Do you ever watch a TV series and notice that the character's behaviour is nothing like what an actual person would behave? How they make decisions not because of concrete reasons, or personality traits, or even irrational thought processes, but rather *only* because the author wanted the story to go that way? Or not even decisions but even random plot points and events also existing just because the author decided on a whim it would be a cool thing to throw in - often with little context and little reason for them to occur? Have you ever read a book with generous amounts of [Applied Phlebotinum](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) sprinkled everywhere, demanding the reader to suspend any deeper interrogation of the mechanics behind the world the story takes place? Or played a video game where all the non-gameplay elements seem like another patchwork of various predictable video game tropes?

Personally it really bothers me when any of those happen and I'm looking for a more concise way to call a situation when those are **not** the case (e.g. when asking for recommendations). Of course I'm not saying all fiction which doesn't match this, but that's beyond the point.

There is the concept of *hard sci-fi* but it seems to refer mostly to scientific accuracy of the story. What I mean is rather the piece of fiction being realistic within its own world - regardless of whether it matches our history and physics or not.

Comment: ***realistic, true to life, lifelike, truthful, faithful, real-life, naturalistic, authentic, genuine, representational, convincing,...***

Comment: Conversely, the story might have [plot holes](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plot_hole).

Comment: So **uncontrived** as to not include gratuitous sex?

Answer (score 3):

When the rules of behaviour as defined by the author are consistently adhered to, the writing in the work of fiction is **coherent** (it may not be realistic, matching everyday life exactly).

> **coherent** [adjective] C2
>
> - If an argument, set of ideas, or a plan is coherent, it is clear and carefully considered, and each part of it connects or follows in a
>   natural or reasonable way.

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/coherent)]

I can't resist adding the not-quite-so-relevant sense here:

> - If someone is coherent, you can understand what that person says.

Answer (score 3):

A story that is realistic within its own world has **internal consistency**:

> A story is made up of multiple components, and it has internal consistency when all of these components operate and abide by the rules and logic that govern the world the story is set in. In other words, internal consistency in a story refers to how closely the components of a story adhere to the rules and logic set out by the story itself. — [The importance of Internal Consistency](https://lgestrella.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/the-importance-of-internal-consistency/)

It’s a phrase that comes up a lot in these types of discussions:

- [It’s OK to whinge about the internal consistency of Sci-Fi shows](https://medium.com/@digitalelysium/xxx-a8ab659b4ea0)
- [The Importance of Internal Consistency in Story Telling](http://www.whiteworld.com/technoland/reviews-techno/reviews2009/TWT-internal-consistency.html)
- [Why Good Writing Matters: Internal Consistency](https://rachellemnshaw.com/blog/2013/02/why-good-writing-matters-internal-consistency)

Comment: Yes. Dr Who has a marvellous way of getting away with change-of-protagonist actor. I think a lot of us found the switch of Dumbledore less ... err .... Bond seems to manage.  The danger inherent in living in Oxford, 1980s Jersey, the Midsomer region or especially Cabot Cove seems a more puzzling conundrum than the Bermuda Triangle.

Comment: I feel like internal consistency refers mostly to the world building and not necessarily to the characters actions being well motivated.

Answer (score 1):

***verisimilitude***

> For example, a fantasy novel that portrays an imaginary world with internal consistency (and using conventions of the fantasy genre) is said to have ***generic verisimilitude***. In other words, (no) matter how outlandish the world of your story is, it should feel real to the reader.

[Master Class "What is Verisimilitude?"](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/what-is-verisimilitude)

> The appearance of being true or real.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/verisimilitude)

The word has quite wide usage in cine...

Answer (score 0):

Novels or movies that intend to present life ***just as it is***, are called

> ***Slice of life***

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_of_life) explains that

> A work that focuses on minute and faithful reproduction of some bit of reality, without selection, organization, or judgment and that every smallest detail is presented with scientific fidelity is an example of ***the "slice of life" novel***.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20slice%20of%20life) defines it as

> an example of what ordinary life is like : something (such as a story
> or movie) that shows what ordinary life is like
>
> - Ex: The story is/shows/presents a slice of life in a small Midwestern town.

[Tvtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SliceOfLife) has an entire article about it, which begins in this way:

> Life, observed and examined. *A cast of characters go about their daily lives, making observations and being themselves*.